# How local use Google closure compiler through php?

Tags: php, javascript, google-closure-compiler

How to use  the closure compiler library (**local**) and php I can obfuscate js?

I will grateful for the code. Perhaps there is some php class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `system()` or the backtick operator to execute it.

Comment: I can run the library without JVM? Perhaps through some PHP module?

Comment: No. It requires Java and since it includes a full JavaScript engine (afaik), porting it to PHP would be pretty much work.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/php-closure/ (can be used local, but uses webservice calls to do the actual magic)